# Mostrar línea de código en debugging con Xcode 11.4

Tags: swift, xcode, depuración

ando iniciando en el uso del debug en xcode 11.4 solo que no encuentro información puntual de como hacer que al inicar el debugging, el breakpoint me mande la línea de código donde se coloca el breakpoint y no el espacio en memoria. Anexo imagenes, las primeras dos son mias y la tercera es un ejemplo de internet.

Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira si estás apuntando al elemento 0 del thread. Lo puedes ver en la parte superior del recuadro Output de consola. En la barra donde tienes los controles para debug.

Comment: Entiendo, pero lo que busco que al hacer debug e ir linea por linea, me de el seguimiento de línea por línea, y no encuentro aun algo que me explique que configuración poner, al iniciar me manda a asignación de memoria. Espero haberme dado a explicar bien.

Comment: Mira en el menu Debug -> Debug Workflow si tienes activado Always Show Disassembly.

Comment: Asi es, tengo activada esa opción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionas en el comentario, para que en el debug se marque el `breakpoint`, debes desmarcar la opción **Always Show Disassembly** en `Debug-> Debug Workflow`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera al ejecutar ya no te mostrará el Assembly.

Comment: Solucionó el problema! Muchisimas gracias!